# The manuscript Summa Logicae (William of Ockham)

Tags: 14th-century, latin-language

The *Summa Logicae* (Latin, in English it's *the Sum of Logic*) is a textbook on logic by [William of Ockham](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_S5dFdpF6xm0/SuC3NlxHmwI/AAAAAAAAAj4/zGiXgFk3NK0/s400/William-of-Ockham-Moscarlop-GNU-free.png) (1323). There are articles about *the Summa Logicae* [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summa_logicae)  and [in Logicmuseum](http://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Summa_Logicae_%28Ockham%29).

It was published in Paris in 1488. There are different typed variants of this textbook, for example [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/pking/articles/Ockham.Summa_logicae.pdf) (in English).

But I can't find any scans or photos of the original handmade manuscript or the original (first) edition. Do you know any links or libraries or museims, where I can find it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a source request.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for references.

Answer (score 3):

The [Logicmuseum](http://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Authors/Ockham/Summa_Logicae#MS) site lists

> Summa Logica: Bruges, Bibl. de la Ville 498 (an. 1340); Avignon, Bibl. Mun. 1086 (1343)

meaning there is (or was) a manuscript in the Bruges municipal library (MS 498) from the year 1340, and one in the Avignon municipal library (MS 1086) from 1343.